# How to move controls in designer mode in Visual Studio 2012?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

I just started using Visual Studio 2012.

Got into the designer, added a button, but I'm unable to move it.

Am I missing something? I thought this worked extremely similar to visual c# express.

Comment: What designer? If WPF, are you using any layout controls like StackPanel? Please be more specific.

Comment: I usually select the control by clicking on it, and then I click and drag it around

Answer (score 0):

Yes you're probably missing something, the designer should move the controls using drag and drop.
I don't know if there's an option to block control (probably there is) and maybe you pressed it

Try to go in the document outline panel there you can block/unblock controls

Answer (score 0):

Sorry guys! seems I had to go to Tools, HTML Designer, CSS Styling and activate "Change positioning to absolute for controls added using Toolbox, paste or drag and drop".

Not sure what the consequences are, though.